# Install Ubuntu between Windows partitions

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, oem, recovery-partition

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 (which is already there) on my machine. I cleared up the space but it is right before two partitions which are named, OEM partition and Recovery partition (screenshot attached).
My main concern is, can I install it without worrying about the partitions that come after the unallocated one?
Will there be any complications in the future?
If there will be, what can I do to avoid them?

[image: Disk Management ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

> My main concern is, can I install it without worrying about the partitions that come after the unallocated one?

Yes.

> Will there be any complications in the future?

Working with partitions always comes with the risk of data loss. Installing additional OS can cause boot problems.

> If there will be, what can I do to avoid them?

Make sure your backups are up to date and restorable. If you don't have backups - you should! Disks don't warn you before they fail, neither does ransomware before encrypting all your files and you won't know when you're accidentally deleting that one file you will badly need later.

Preferably make a full disk image. Make it on an external device (USB drive or NAS) which is not directly connected during installation. Personally I'm a fan of Clonezilla. Macrium Reflect has good reputation too.